# Exclude Logs from Datadog Ingestion

Tags: kubernetes, logging, datadog

I have a kubernetes cluster that's running datadog and some microservices. Each microservice makes healthchecks every 5 seconds to make sure the service is up and running. I want to exclude these healthcheck logs from being ingested into Datadog.

I think I need to use `log_processing_rules` and I've tried that but the healthcheck logs are still making it into the logs section of Datadog. My current Deployment looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
[ ... SNIP ... ]
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-service
        version: "fac8fb13"
      annotations:
        rollme: "IO2ad"
        tags.datadoghq.com/env: development
        tags.datadoghq.com/version: "fac8fb13"
        tags.datadoghq.com/service: my-service
        tags.datadoghq.com/my-service.logs: |
          [{
            "source": my-service,
            "service": my-service,
            "log_processing_rules": [
              {
                "type": "exclude_at_match",
                "name": "exclude_healthcheck_logs",
                "pattern": "\"RequestPath\": \"\/health\""
              }
            ]
          }]
```

and the logs coming out of the kubernetes pod:

```
$ kubectl logs my-service-pod

{
  "@t": "2022-01-07T19:13:05.3134483Z",
  "@m": "Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.64.0.80:5000/health - - - 200 - text/plain 7.5992ms",
  "@i": "REDACTED",
  "ElapsedMilliseconds": 7.5992,
  "StatusCode": 200,
  "ContentType": "text/plain",
  "ContentLength": null,
  "Protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
  "Method": "GET",
  "Scheme": "http",
  "Host": "10.64.0.80:5000",
  "PathBase": "",
  "Path": "/health",
  "QueryString": "",
  "HostingRequestFinishedLog": "Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://10.64.0.80:5000/health - - - 200 - text/plain 7.5992ms",
  "EventId": {
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "RequestFinished"
  },
  "SourceContext": "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics",
  "RequestId": "REDACTED",
  "RequestPath": "/health",
  "ConnectionId": "REDACTED",
  "dd_service": "my-service",
  "dd_version": "54aae2b5",
  "dd_env": "development",
  "dd_trace_id": "REDACTED",
  "dd_span_id": "REDACTED"
}
```

EDIT: Removed 2nd element of the `log_processing_rules` array above as I've tried with 1 and 2 elements in the rules array.

EDIT2: I've also tried changing `log_processing_rules` type to INCLUDE at match in an attempt to figure this out:

```
"log_processing_rules": [
  {
    "type": "include_at_match",
    "name": "testing_include_at_match",
    "pattern": "somepath"
  }
]
```

and I'm still getting the health logs in Datadog (in theory I should not as `/health` is not part of the matching pattern)

Comment: [In a Kubernetes environment](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/?tab=kubernetes#exclude-at-match), use the pod annotation `ad.datadoghq.com` on your pod to specify the `log_processing_rules`. Try to change it from `tags.datadoghq.com/my-service.logs` to `ad.datadoghq.com/my-service.logs`

Comment: I just had an "oh ship" moment with this, but changing the annotations to `ad.datadoghq.com/my-service.logs` still doesn't prevent the logs from being ingested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of these answers are correct in their own ways, but my specific issue was that the Datadog annotations for the `source` and `service` were not properly quoted:

```
        ad.datadoghq.com/my-service.logs: |
          [{
            "source": "my-service",    # Needs Quotes
            "service": "my-service",   # Needs Quotes
            "log_processing_rules": [
              {
                "type": "exclude_at_match",
                "name": "exclude_healthcheck_logs",
                "pattern": "\"RequestPath\": \"\/health\""
              }
            ]
          }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're defining multiple patterns; the [docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/?tab=configurationfile#exclude-at-match) state, `If you want to match one or more patterns you must define them in a single expression.`

Try somtething like this and see what happens:

```
"log_processing_rules": [
  {
    "type": "exclude_at_match",
    "name": "exclude_healthcheck_logs",
    "pattern": "\/health|\"RequestPath\": \"\/health\""
  }
```

Comment: Edited above question to state that I've tried with 1 and 2 elements in the `log_processing_rules` array

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you are applying the label `com.datadoghq.ad.logs` to the *service container* which is generating the log messages... not the *Datadog agent container*. (That was my mistake.)