# Restrict/Exclude specific logs from Airflow to Datadog

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-taskflow

We are observing Airflow is sending large amount of logs to Datadog and we want to restrict/Reduce these logs by excluding logs from below tasks:

- pod_manager.py
- base.py
- base_aws.py
- logging_mixin.py

Do we have any configuration settings where I can define this requirement?

We have Airflow-2.0 running on Kubernetes.

Comment: To send only a specific subset of logs to Datadog, use the log_processing_rules parameter in your configuration file with the exclude_at_match or include_at_match type.
Refer to this [doc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/?tab=configurationfile#exclude-at-match) for more information and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks @HemanthKumar. I am trying to implement it but I am not understanding which component of airflow generates above logs as i only can see yaml file for Schedular and Webserver.

Comment: Can you try as below to exclude logs from the tasks named pod_manager.py, base.py, base_aws.py, drgn_kubernetes_pod_operator.py, logging_mixin.py, and standard_task_runner.py .

 Can you use the following configuration settings:
[logging]
`exclude_tasks=pod_manager.py,base.py,base_aws.py,drgn_kubernetes_pod_operator.py,logging_mixin.py,standard_task_runner.py`

These settings can be added to the `airflow.cfg` file, which is located in the Airflow home directory. Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70957601/19230181)

Comment: @HemanthKumar I tested above method in my local and its not working. I can see the logs of task after excluding it using above mentioned method. Please let me know if anything else i can try.

Comment: Have you tried using the solution provided in the first comment. Try this configuaration file in airflow.cfg and  let me know the error you are getting?

Comment: @HemanthKumar yes 1st solution will work but I don't understand which component of airflow is generating above mentioned logs. Will all the logs be generated by the schedular?

Comment: I think yes can you have a look at this schedular and try with the first solution.

Comment: @HemanthKumarI tested and the first solution is working fine. I am able to exclude all the logs using the.* prefix. I am struggling to make regex to exclude above all. I tried regex like "^.*(pod_manager| base|base_aws|logging_mixin).*$", This will remove only the name of the task but except for these words, the entire line will be present in the logs. Is this regex looks fine? am I doing any mistake?

Comment: Seems to be your regex is also fine and can you try it once. If its not working then you can use a negative lookahead assertion as below : 
`"^.*(?!pod_manager|base|base_aws|logging_mixin).*$"`. Refer to this [A regular expression to exclude a word/string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078915/) and [How to exclude a specific string constant? for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395177/).

Comment: No, these regex patterns are also not working. When I am doing exclude_all or include_all then it is working but with any kinda pattern its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send only a specific subset of logs to Datadog, use the log_processing_rules parameter in your configuration file with the exclude_at_match or include_at_match type. Apply this to your schedular which generating the logs. Refer to this [Datadog official doc](https://docs.datadoghq.com/agent/logs/advanced_log_collection/?tab=configurationfile#exclude-at-match) for more information.